# How to reach jpeg files in stored in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, streamlit

I deployed the web application. It is successful but my image files doesn't appear on web page.
I receive No such file or directory: 'gs://imajo/media/predict_resim.jpg' error.
Here is the code I typed. I typed it on google cloud. how can I solve this in an easy python way?

```
 htp7='gs://imajo/media/planner_resim.jpg'
 image7 = Image.open('htp7')
```

and this is the deployed app. (It is About anaylisis page)
https://easy-inventory-planner.ew.r.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to access Google Storage file using Google Storage Protocol link which is private and you need authentication to get that file.

**Python Google Storage Client** 
In order to get file on Google Storage with that link you can use **Python Google Storage Client**, more info and examples on how to authenticate and download file can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#cloud-console

**Making File Public**

Other option is to make your file public, that way you will get publicly accessible link (http) to your file, and then your solution will work.

- Find your file in Google Cloud Storage Browser (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browse)
- Click on three dots on the far right side of your file
- Choose **edit permissions**
- **Add entry** with **Public**, **allUsers** and **Read**
- Once you **Save**, you will have **Copy URL** in the **Public access** column on file listing.
- This link is publicly available.
- Paste https link to your program and it will work. This link is https:// instead of gs:// which is only accessible through client. It looks something like this: https://storage.googleapis.com/imajo/media/predict_resim.jpg

Comment: thank you but it still gives same error. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Did you change to url which is copied?

Comment: You will get new link starting with https:// not gs://. Something like this: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcloudping/whatever.jpg

Comment: that was gold. the first step of the process. I am using streamlit and this code worked :  htp6='https://storage.googleapis.com/imajo/media/predict_resim.jpg'
 #image6 = Image.open(htp6)
 st.image(htp6, caption= 'Predictability Analysis', width=310) thanks @Dejan

Comment: @Ozgur I've added missing step in answer, if you like the answer please accept it, that way others will also know solution worked. I'm glad we fixed your issue, happy coding!

Comment: On the left side of the answer there is checkmark    (below number of votes), that shows which of the answers worked for you. You click it to accept the answer.